# Saving an uploaded file and returning form data

Tags: f#, network-file-transfer

I am new to F#. This code is basically a port I did from C#.  I am sure there is room for a ton of improvement, so how can I improve and make this more efficient?

```
let SingleFIle (req : HttpRequestMessage) dirName typeDir (fileType : string) userName 
        clearDir deleteExistingFile =
            async{
                // Check Request
                if not (req.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
                then
                    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType)
                else 

                    // create temp file dir
                    let tempFileFolder = 
                        HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/TempFileUploads")

                    // create the temp file folder
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(tempFileFolder) |> ignore

                    // create provider
                    let provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(tempFileFolder)

                    // save file data
                    try
                        // create the server path
                        let dirPath = ref ""
                        if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName)
                        then
                            dirPath := 
                                HttpContext.Current.Server
                                    .MapPath(@"~/Uploads/" + typeDir + @"/" + dirName)
                        else
                            dirPath := 
                                HttpContext.Current.Server
                                    .MapPath(@"~/Uploads/" + typeDir + @"/" + dirName +
                                        @"/" + userName)

                        // clear directory if true
                        if clearDir
                        then
                            if Directory.Exists(!dirPath)
                            then 
                                Directory.Delete(!dirPath, true)

                        // create the final directory path
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(!dirPath) |> ignore

                        // save to provider

                        let! readToProvider = 
                            (req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync provider) |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult

                        // file name and type check
                        let fileNameAndTypeIsValid =

                            // file name length list
                            let nameLength =
                                [
                                    for x in provider.FileData ->
                                        x.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Length
                                ]

                            // file type length
                            let fileTypeList =
                                [
                                    for x in provider.FileData ->
                                        x.Headers.ContentType.MediaType
                                         .Substring(0, fileType.Length)
                                ]

                            // nameLength & fileType valid check
                            let nameLengthNotValid =
                                    query{
                                        for x in nameLength do
                                        exists (x <= 2)
                                    }

                            let fileTypeNotValid =
                                query{
                                    for x in fileTypeList do
                                    exists (x <> fileType)
                                }

                            (not nameLengthNotValid) && (not fileTypeNotValid) && 
                                (provider.FormData.Count > 0)

                        // if valid then create file details
                        if fileNameAndTypeIsValid
                        then
                            // get the current file info
                            let fileInfo =
                                new FileInfo(provider.FileData.ElementAt(0)
                                    .LocalFileName)

                            // get the extension
                            let stripQuotes = new FileInfo(provider.FileData.ElementAt(0)
                                        .Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName
                                        .Replace(@"""", String.Empty))
                            let ext = stripQuotes.Extension

                            // create new file path and move file
                            File.Move(fileInfo.FullName, (Path.Combine(!dirPath, fileInfo.Name + ext)))

                            // create file Url
                            let fileUrl = ref ""
                            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userName))
                            then
                                fileUrl := @"/Uploads/" + typeDir + @"/" + dirName + @"/" +
                                    fileInfo.Name + ext
                            else
                                fileUrl := @"/Uploads/" + typeDir + @"/" + dirName + @"/" +
                                    userName + @"/" + fileInfo.Name + ext

                            provider.FormData.Add("FileUrl", !fileUrl)

                            // delete existing files if true
                            if deleteExistingFile
                            then
                                for x in provider.FormData
                                            .GetValues("ExistingPath") do
                                    File.Delete(
                                        System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment
                                            .MapPath(x))



                            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, provider.FormData)
                        else
                            return req.CreateResponse HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
                    with
                        | ex -> return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a cleaned up version. It's by no means exhaustive, but may get you thinking about other ways to improve it. Some of the changes:

- removed comments (they didn't add anything since the code is adequately descriptive)
- replaced `ref`s with `let`-bound expressions
- replaced `Substring` with slicing
- cleaned up some of the logic
- refactored file validation into a separate function
- replaced `query` expressions with (more suitable) collection functions
- replaced unused exception with wildcard pattern

  ```
  let singleFile 
      (req : HttpRequestMessage) 
      dirName 
      typeDir 
      (fileType : string) 
      userName 
      clearDir 
      deleteExistingFile =

      let isValidFile (fileData: seq<MultipartFileData>) =
          let nameLength =
              [
                  for x in fileData ->
                      x.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Length
              ]

          let fileTypeList =
              [
                  for x in fileData ->
                      x.Headers.ContentType.MediaType.[..fileType.Length-1]
              ]

          let nameLengthNotValid = nameLength |> List.exists ((>=) 2)
          let fileTypeNotValid = fileTypeList |> List.exists ((<>) fileType)

          not (nameLengthNotValid || fileTypeNotValid)

      async {
          if not (req.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent()) then
              return req.CreateResponse HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType
          else 

              let tempFileFolder = 
                  HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath @"~/TempFileUploads"

              Directory.CreateDirectory tempFileFolder |> ignore

              let provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(tempFileFolder)

              try
                  let dirPath = 
                      let path = 
                          @"~/Uploads/" + typeDir + @"/" + dirName 
                          + if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace userName then "" else @"/" + userName
                      HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath path

                  if clearDir && Directory.Exists dirPath then 
                      Directory.Delete(dirPath, true)

                  // create the final directory path
                  Directory.CreateDirectory dirPath |> ignore

                  let! readToProvider = 
                      req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync provider |> Async.AwaitIAsyncResult

                  let fileNameAndTypeIsValid = isValidFile provider.FileData && provider.FormData.Count > 0

                  if fileNameAndTypeIsValid then
                      let fileInfo =
                          new FileInfo(
                              provider.FileData.ElementAt(0).LocalFileName
                          )

                      let ext = 
                          Path.GetExtension(
                              provider.FileData.ElementAt(0)
                                  .Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName
                                  .Replace(@"""", String.Empty)
                          )

                      File.Move(fileInfo.FullName, Path.Combine(dirPath, fileInfo.Name + ext))

                      let fileUrl = 
                          @"/Uploads/" + typeDir + @"/" + dirName + @"/"  
                          + if String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace userName then "" else userName + @"/" 
                          + fileInfo.Name + ext

                      provider.FormData.Add("FileUrl", fileUrl)

                      if deleteExistingFile then
                          for x in provider.FormData.GetValues("ExistingPath") do
                              File.Delete (System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(x))

                      return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, provider.FormData)
                  else
                      return req.CreateResponse HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
              with
                  | _ -> return req.CreateResponse HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError
      }
  ```

Comment: Awesome! F# is simply amazing.  The more I learn the more I'm blown away by how expressive it is.